# Need Help to build query

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-5

[My table looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJes3.jpg)

Now I want to have list of year where leader_board_no is not equals 1 .

My Expected result is :

year

---

- 2016
- 2017

But when I run

```
select `year` from `leaderboard_log` where `leader_board_no` != 1 and `year` != 2017 group by `year`
```

I am getting only 2016 .

Please some one help me to build the query .

Comment: No pictures, thanks. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You are saying explicitly `where year != 2017`, how can `2017` be returned? Leave out the `year` condition and you should get expected results.

Comment: try without group by clause, if you need to grouping, you have to select another unique column

Comment: I need where leader_board_no !=1 and year !=2017,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Got My Ans**

```
SELECT
  `year`
FROM
  `leaderboard_log`
WHERE
  id NOT IN(
  SELECT
    id
  FROM
    `leaderboard_log`
  WHERE
    `leader_board_no` = 1 AND `year` = 2017
)
GROUP BY
  `year`
```

In Laravel 5.2 :

```
         $getYears = LeaderboardLog::select('year','id')
         ->whereNotIn('id', function($q) use ($current_leaderboard,$current_year){
              $q->select('id')
              ->where('leader_board_no','=',$current_leaderboard)
              ->where('year','=',$current_year);
          })->groupBy('year')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you require all results, except for when

1. Year is equal to 2017

and

2. Leader Board is equal to 1.

You can use NOT query

```
where not (year = 2017 and LEADER_BOARD = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you require your results to meet the `leader_board_no <> 1` condition ONLY when it is in `year = 2017`, then simply use `OR`

```
select `year` from `leaderboard_log` where `leader_board_no` != 1 or `year` != 2017 group by `year`
```